# Share access to google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I am currently using the Google Cloud Shell, and I wish to share access of it including the storage to someone so how can I do it.(I am quiet new to all this)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more on the scenario?

Comment: I have recently started to host a minecraft server on google cloud shell using https://github.com/lordofwizard/mcserver. I was trying to find a way through which you can share access to the shell so my friend can start the server without me being online